# Issue in SPI while communicating between stm32f4 and arduino

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f4discovery

In my spi code without HAL libraries I am not able to send data rather than 0xFF if I am sending any data it is by default sending as 0xFF.Here is my code:

```
#include <stm32f4xx.h>

uint8_t i = 100;
int j = 0;
uint8_t data = 82;

void afio_config(void);
void spi_init(void);

int main(void)
{
    afio_config();
    spi_init();
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI2_IRQn);
    while(1)
    {
    }
}

void afio_config()
{
    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= (1<<1)|(1<<2);
    RCC -> APB1ENR |= (1<<14);
    GPIOB -> MODER |= (1<<21)|(1<<24);
    GPIOC -> MODER |= (1<<7)|(1<<5);
    GPIOB ->OTYPER &= ~((1<<12)&(1<<10));
    GPIOC ->OTYPER &= ~((1<<2)&(1<<3));
    GPIOB -> OSPEEDR |= (1<<24)|(1<<20);
    GPIOC -> OSPEEDR |= (1<<4)|(1<<6);
    GPIOB -> PUPDR |= (1<<25)|(1<<21);
    GPIOC -> PUPDR |= (1<<4)|(1<<6);
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] |= (1<<14)|(1<<12)|(1<<10)|(1<<8);
    GPIOB -> AFR[1] |= (1<<10)|(1<<8);
}


void spi_init()
{
    SPI2 ->CR1 |= (1<<4)|(1<<5);
    SPI2 ->CR1 |= (1<<15)|(1<<14);
    SPI2 ->CR1 |= (1<<9)|(1<<8);
    SPI2 ->CR2 |= (1<<7);
    SPI2 ->CR1 |= (1<<2);
    SPI2 ->CR1 |= (1<<6);
    GPIOB ->ODR &= ~(1<<12);
}

void SPI2_IRQHandler()
{
    SPI2 ->DR = data;
}
```

Comment: Do not use this magic numbers. Use human readable symbols as defined in the CMSIS headers. It is not 8bit simple AVR

Comment: actually I am doing register level coding for this arm i dont like to use ready made headers.

Comment: Ty for your advice

Comment: So no one will answer your questions. ARM bare register programmers use ARM CMSIS headers to understand other code without wasting the time decoding bit numbers. Using "magic" numbers is the best way to get into the troubles Respect other people time.

Comment: BTW you should not use the `RCC`, `GPIO` defines and typedefs as well. Use `*((volatile uint32_t *) (((uint32_t)0x40000000U) + 0x00005400U + 0x8)) |= (1<<14)|(1<<12)|(1<<10)|(1<<8);` instead for more "bare metal" programming

Comment: And how could you do this: **#include <stm32f4xx.h>**? Do not include it as you: *`actually I am doing register level coding for this arm i dont like to use ready made headers.`*

Comment: Thankyou so much.